# Help with QueryFilter

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, c#

I have a query filter which works if pass a new instance of QueryFilterClass without setting any properties.  But it breaks if I set the WhereClause.  I get an error 
0x80040358

```
queryFilter.WhereClause = "HouseNum = '4501'"; //this is my WhereClause which will make table.Search(queryFilter, true) break
```

This is my code which works:

```
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
//queryFilter.WhereClause = "HouseNum = '4501'";

IQueryFilterDefinition queryFilterDef = (IQueryFilterDefinition)queryFilter;
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(dbfPath);
String dbfDirectoryPath = file.Directory.FullName;
IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
Workspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(dbfDirectoryPath, 0) as Workspace;
IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;
String dbfTable = file.Name;
ITable table = featureWorkspace.OpenTable(dbfTable);

int shapeIndex = table.FindField("Shape");

try
{
using (ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
{
ICursor cursor = table.Search(queryFilter, true);
comReleaser.ManageLifetime(cursor);
IRow row = null;
while ((row = cursor.NextRow()) != null)
{
object o = row.get_Value(shapeIndex);
IPoint p = o as IPoint;
p.Project(gcs); 
double doubleX = p.X;
double doubleY = p.Y; 
}
}
}
```

How can I fix my WhereClause?  Also does QueryFilter support the SQL LIKE Condition?

Comment: what line does it throw the exception on?

Comment: Could it be that `HouseNum` is not a valid column name for that layer, or that the data type is an integer and not a string?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall It throws the exception on this line, table.Search(queryFilter, true)

Comment: HouseNum seems like it might be a numeric field, in which case you would get an error.  Have you confirmed that it is a text field?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall Yeah, I opened the DBF in Access and its a text field.  The weird thing is that I can't even add HouseNum to my queryFilter.SubFields list.

Comment: What does table.FindField("HouseNum") return?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall It returns -1, I guess that's the answer, thansk for helping me figure it out.

Comment: @Kirk It would be good to memorialize your answer by collecting these comments into a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does support the LIKE. Try this:

```
queryFilter.WhereClause = "HouseNum LIKE '4501'";
```

EDIT #1:

Also you might want to try using the "serverContext.CreateObject"

http://nicogis.blogspot.com/2010/02/server-context-empty.html

EDIT #2:

Also try setting the SubFields.

queryFilter.SubFields = "HouseNum";

Comment: IMO servercontext is a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: I believe Kirk's answer is more correct in the context of what was asked and how it was solved and should be the one marked as accepted.

Comment: The query format and capabilities in terms of supported clauses and constructs is always determined by the underlying storage. One needs to be careful since the exact syntax for LIKE differs for, say, shapefiles and personal geodatabases. The ISQLSyntax interface provides the necessary information.

Answer (score 7):

It is probably best practice to confirm that a field exists before using it in a queryfilter.

This can be done using the [ITable.FindField](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FindField_Method/0025000000w1000000/) or [IFeatureclass.FindField](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureClass_Interface/0025000002qs000000/) method.

Comment: +1 Validating the data model (at least on the column naming level) is a good thing to do before letting your code proceed any futher. If you do not do that, you risk getting a non-informative exception later, making the code much harder to debug.

Answer (score 4):

I often see people asking how to figure out what "erro x" is. So even though someone already potentially answered this question, I will still show you how decode the HRESULT value.

All you have to do is grab the hex number, interpret it as a *signed* 32 bit number, and then search for it on google (or the ESRI site). If it is a GDB error, it will show up as on of the value in the FDO error constant or the sdeErro constants. I just use python like so:

```
rburhum@Router-MBP.local ~ $ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i = 0x80040358
>>> s32 = (i + 2**31) % 2**32 - 2**31
>>> s32
-2147220648L
>>>
```

As you can see, the error is -2147220648 , if you are using a search engine, search for 2147220648 (without the minus) because search engines usually have a meaning for the minus in front.

Right away, [my google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=2147220648)  shows an [fdoError constant](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/fdoError.htm) as a result.

```
FDO_E_TABLE_COLUMN_NOT_FOUND    -2147220648 A column was specified that does not exist.
```

The table you are querying does not have the field you want.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Select by Attributes dialog, manually create the query, and compare that syntax with your WhereClause.

Comment: based on earlier questions, he doesn't have desktop - just arcengine.